# Why am I getting a 'Access denied for user' error when accessing a MySQL database on Laravel through CyberPanel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, database, host, cyber-panel

I build a laravel project and deployed it in cyberpanel vps.
I clear the cache and set all configurations and environment.

I create a database in my host "chih_chihab2023" and give it password,
I copied the database infos to my .env file and import the sql file in phpmyadmin in the host.
but this problem is appearing.
I tried many solutions but no one get a result please help me.
[image: image of error]

I want to know the causes of this problem and methods to solve it.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you on a remote machine by change, otherwise this might prove useful; [How to Allow Remote Connections to MySQL](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/mysql-remote-connection)

Comment: Did you clear the cache? ```php artisan config:cache``` Or make sure all the credentials are correct